# Android - Work with 24 hours time intervals

Tags: android, sqlite, time, intervals

I dont know how to express myself very well about this doubt, but i will try best.

My app will have various quests (hosted on a database) that the user must try to make them.

I want the app to update the quest with a random quest from the database and display it on the app during 24 hours, and the after that 24 hours display another one, etc, i think you understood it now.

How can i achieve that ?

I searched the web and i cant find anything that suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You store a timestamp on the users phone. When he logs in you compare the timestamp with the current time. If there are 24 hours passed you update the quest and the stored timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 public static void setAlarm(Context context, String action, int actionCode, long syncTime)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, actionCode);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, actionCode + 1000, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + syncTime, syncTime, alarmIntent);
    }


public class AlarmIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int action = intent.getIntExtra(AlarmUtil.ACTION, 0);
//Perform action here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TimerTask method, setting firstTime to a time you want to refresh the taskand the setting the period to 24-hours like

```
Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
```

Then do your random thing to pick a new quest and flag this a active.